# How to show a value in a textfield in Ireport?

Tags: textfield, ireport

I'm currently creating a reports related to business organizations. The report I need to make is one that shows a text whenever a certain value is equal to zero.

e.g.

I have php file that passes parameters to my ireport to create the report. In the php file there is a dropdown box which selects the departments(all values except the selection ALL DEPARTMENTS are from the database, the all departments throws back a value of zero.)

I was wondering as to how the value ALL DEPARTMENTS would show in the textfield in my ireport if the throwned value is equal to zero.

I have already tried using case statements in my where but to no avail. 
Thanks and I do hope you could help me on this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use text field expression, for example:

```xml
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{departmentFilter}.equalsIgnoreCase("ALL DEPARTMENTS") ? "All departments in company" : $P{departmentFilter}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Comment: sadly, it still does not work since what I pass are integer parameters, but thanks anyway for answering.

Comment: Can you publish light version of your template? I'll try to check it